# Match color style of several shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile, geology

I have several shapefiles that depict the geology of an area.
I'm having a hard time to match the colors for the common geological formations of these shapefiles.
Can you please guide me?
I can do it manually but it will take forever.
[image]

Comment: What version of ArcMap?

Comment: Versionof ArcMap 10.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) all the shapefiles to one shapefile, set the symbology of that shapefile using the shared attribute (Formation) and then import the symbology to all separate shapefiles under Symbology tab - Import.

Comment: That worked perfectly.
One last question, even if that is a problem of the shapefile I think.
In some shapefile contacts the color of the formation is not the same.
The formation description is not the same but that doesn't make any sense.
Is the shapefile just wrong or am I missing something?

https://s9.postimg.org/hfw8b399b/Untitled.png

Comment: Also, I was advised by a professor to copy paste all polygons in order to have the same colors.
Does that have the same result as merging?

Comment: "In some shapefile contacts the color of the formation is not the same. The formation description is not the same but that doesn't make any sense. Is the shapefile just wrong or am I missing something?" I would Think the shapefiles are wrong, maybe the formation attribute is not spelled the same or with a blank space.

Comment: "Also, I was advised by a professor to copy paste all polygons in order to have the same colors. Does that have the same result as merging?" You mean by start edit session on one shapefile and copy paste the geometry to this from another shape file? If the shapefile you are copying has columns not existing in the shape you are editing these will not be created. If you merge the shapefiles all columns will end up in the resulting shapefile.

Comment: Regarding the contacts problem, I clicked identify and indeed the formation is different, even though it shouldn't.

Regarding the copy/pasting, what I meant is go to start editing, right click on the shape file, select all, edit copy and edit paste.Select target and then select another shapefile to copy.

Answer (score 1):

If these are using  unique values symbols, I created an Add-In that will copy the colours from the second layer in the TOC to the first layer.  You may need to rearrange your layers a few times if you have more than two to match.  It will only match colours where the attribute values match.

You can download the [Layer Colors AddIn](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-7481) from GeoNet.

Comment: I'm trying to add it through Add-In manager-->customise--> add from file and I get this message:

No GUI components found in this Add-In.
Add-In version does not match.

If I just double-click the file, I get a message that it was unable to find a matching ArcGis installation.
I click ok, I get a message that the installation was successful, but I can't find the add in.

Comment: I thought it was made with 10.2 but it may be 10.3 which might be why it doesn't work. I'll have a closer look

Comment: Is there any other way if that's not possible?
Maybe from symbology tab through import?
I can select import symbology definition from another layer in the map or from a layer file.
Then I choose the right value field and then I press "add values".
I guess this adds all the values that are not common is that right?

The outcome is a better result but not perfect, some contacts don't have the same color but many do. Maybe I'm missing something?